# обработка нескольких форм на одной странице

Tags: php

Есть 3 формы на странице. Значения полей в зависимости от отправленной формы попадают в массив (`$form _data`).

```
if (isset($_POST['login_button'])){
    $subject = " registration ";
    $form_data = array("name" => "{$_POST['name_call_me']}",
                       "question" => "{$_POST['question']}",
                       "phone" => "{$_POST['phone_call_me']}"
                       );    
} elseif (isset($_POST['send_btn_call_me'])){
    $subject = " did't find a product you need ";
    $form_data = array("login" => "{$_POST['login']}",
                       "password" => "{$_POST['password']}"
                      );   
} elseif (isset($_POST['contact_sent'])){
    $subject = " contact ";
    $form_data = array("name" =>"{$_POST['contact_name']}",
                       "email" => "{$_POST['contact_email']}",
                       "phone" => "{$_POST['contact_phone']}",
                       "subject" => "{$_POST['contact_subject']}",
                       "massage" => "{$_POST['contact_massage']}"
                      );
};
```

Вопрос в том как реализовать функцию обратной связи, в зависимости от отправленной формы. Примерно так :

```
function sent(принимаемый массив $form_data){
в зависимости от выбора формы отправка письма на почту, используя значения из принятого массива}
```

Comment: а в чем именно у Вас проблема/затруднение ?

Comment: трудность в написании самой функции для обработки той или иной формы, а именно в принятии в качестве нужных параметров функции. То есть нажал отправку 1 формы - отправили письмо с нужной темой, нажали на 2 форму - отправили письмо уже с 2й темой , и тд

Comment: для начала `function sent($_POST)`, и далее разбираете $_POST  и генерируете отправку. для более детального ответа напишите код Вашей отправки письма в вопросе.

Comment: функцию mail нужно запихнуть в сам funtion sent() 
выглядит так 
mail($to, $subject, $massage);
$massage принимаем исходя из принятой формы , например если тыкнуть login_button форму тогда $massage = $form_data["name"].$form_data["question"].$form_data["phone"];

Comment: добавили ответ, Вы так хотели сделать(если нет, уточните что не так)?

Comment: пример указан ниже

Answer (score 1):

```
function sent($subject, $form_data){
    $to = "нужный email"(если из $_POST, то нужно добавить параметр в функцию)
    $massage = implode(" ", $form_data);
    if(mail($to, $subject, $massage)){
        echo 'The message was sent';
    }
    else{
        echo 'The message not sent';
    }
}

if (isset($_POST['login_button'])){
    $subject = " registration ";
    $form_data = array("name" => "{$_POST['name_call_me']}",
                       "question" => "{$_POST['question']}",
                       "phone" => "{$_POST['phone_call_me']}"
                       );
} elseif (isset($_POST['send_btn_call_me'])){
    $subject = " did't find a product you need ";
    $form_data = array("login" => "{$_POST['login']}",
                       "password" => "{$_POST['password']}"
                      );   
} elseif (isset($_POST['contact_sent'])){
    $subject = " contact ";
    $form_data = array("name" =>"{$_POST['contact_name']}",
                       "email" => "{$_POST['contact_email']}",
                       "phone" => "{$_POST['contact_phone']}",
                       "subject" => "{$_POST['contact_subject']}",
                       "massage" => "{$_POST['contact_massage']}"
                      );
};
function sent($subject,$form_data);
```

Answer (score 0):

хотелось что-то по типу -

```
function sent_form( $form_data ) {
$to = 'test@gmail.com';
$massage = implode(" ", $form_data);
if(isset($_POST['login_button'])){
    $selected_form = 'key1';
} elseif (isset($_POST['send_btn_call_me'])){
    $selected_form = 'key2';
} elseif (isset($_POST['contact_sent'])){
    $selected_form = 'key3';
}; 

   switch($selected_form){
    case 'key1':
    $subject = " registration ";
    $form_data = array("name" => $_POST['name_call_me'],
                  "question" => $_POST['question'],
                  "phone" => $_POST['phone_call_me']
                 ); 
    mail($to, $subject, $massage);
    break;
    case 'key2':        
    $subject = " did't find a product you need ";
    $form_data = array("login" => $_POST['login'],
                       "password" => $_POST['password']
                      );
    mail($to, $subject, $massage);
    break;
    case 'key3':
    $subject = " contact ";
    $form_data = array("name" =>"{$_POST['contact_name']}",
                    "email" => $_POST['contact_email'],
                    "phone" => $_POST['contact_phone'],
                    "subject" => $_POST['contact_subject'],
                    "massage" => $_POST['contact_massage']
                  );

    mail($to, $subject, $massage);
    break;
    }}
```

не уверен что правильно всё,
но как и где вызывать подобную функцию , что бы она обрабатывала нужную форму

Comment: вся функция сводится к 10 строчкам из нашего ответа, посмотрите его внимательнее.

Comment: если это пример, пожалуйста опубликуйте его в тексте вопроса и не публикуйте как ответ.